# Elasticssearch v2 query that needs updating to v5.

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have this query that needs updating to ES v5 
How would you do that?

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "@timestamp:[2017-08-16T17:08:51.548680+01:00 TO 2017-08-16T18:08:51.548565+01:00] AND type:farm-stats,proc_io.read_bytes:total"
    }
  },
   "aggs": {
      "top_tags": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "proc_io.read_bytes",
            "interval": "minute"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you have ideas how to do it with python elasticsearch dsl even better :).

Answer (score 0):

can you explain what makes you think, that this does not work on 5.x? Can you show the exception you got? Looks actually fine.

Comment: I am getting an error when I do a curl:
reason: "failed to parse query"
This used to work on ES v2.